# Node.js runs in cmd but not in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation

I ran this code, which is in jquery pro 2.0 book:

```
var http = require("http");
var querystring = require("querystring");
  
var port = 80;
  
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log("[200 OK] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
  
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        var dataObj = new Object();
        var cType = req.headers["content-type"];
        var fullBody = "";
          
        if (cType && cType.indexOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") > -1) {
            req.on("data", function(chunk) { fullBody += chunk.toString();});
            req.on("end", function() {
                res.writeHead(200, "OK", {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                res.write("<html><head><title>Post data</title></head><body>");
                res.write("<style>th, td {text-align:left; padding:5px; color:black}\n");
                res.write("th {background-color:grey; color:white; min-width:10em}\n");
                res.write("td {background-color:lightgrey}\n");
                res.write("caption {font-weight:bold}</style>");
                res.write("<table border='1'><caption>Form Data</caption>");
                res.write("<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th>");
                var dBody = querystring.parse(fullBody);
                for (var prop in dBody) {
                    res.write("<tr><td>" + prop + "</td><td>"
                        + dBody[prop] + "</td></tr>");
                }
                res.write("</table></body></html>");
                res.end();
            });
        }
    }
  
}).listen(port);
console.log("Ready on port " + port);
```

using the command line node.exe formserver.js
This returns 'ready on port 90'.
Anytime I make a call to localhost:90 on my browser it registers the request in cmd as '200 OK GET to /'

In the browser it says 'waiting for localhost' for about a minute. Then it fails with 'no data received message'.

In the book the author is using a www. extensions to serve his pages, however, I'm using 'localhost' like most normal beginners

I have two questions, how do I get the localhost to load and where do I save my html files so that the localhost will see them. Is it in the same folder where the above code is saved? Or in the html docs in the nodejs install?

Comment: There's a very good chance your `cType` isn't what you expect. Log it and find out.

Comment: @Jarek specifying port 80 did not change the above issue unfortunately

Comment: @JanDvorak jQuery pro is a book, sorry, should have mentioned that

Comment: @RyanKinal how do I 'log it', yes, I'm completely new to this

Comment: Log and check the values - console.log(cType)

Comment: @RyanKinal The command prompt returns the console calls above but the browser console does not register any calls. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to receive the data

Comment: Are you getting errors? Which console calls? What does the command prompt say? Are your callbacks being called?

Comment: @user2888246 where are you returning anything to the browser?

Comment: @RyanKinal there are no errors, in my command prompt it says Ready on port 80, then every time I go into localhost in my browser the command prompt writes '200 OK GET to /'. In the browser there are no errors, after a minute it just says 'no data received

Comment: Item #2 in @mainguy's answer is the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some tips to get you some results:

1. Don't listen on port 80
2. You are reacting to POST - The browser will make a GET when you just type in the url
3. Buy a book about node.js too:-)
4. use these modifications to get at least some results:

   ```
   var http = require("http");
   var querystring = require("querystring");

   var port = 8888;

   http.createServer(function (req, res) {
       console.log("[200 OK] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);

       if (req.method == "GET") {
           var dataObj = new Object();
           var cType = req.headers["content-type"];
           var fullBody = "";


                   res.writeHead(200, "OK", {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                   res.write("<html><head><title>Post data</title></head><body>");
                   res.write("<style>th, td {text-align:left; padding:5px; color:black}\n");
                   res.write("th {background-color:grey; color:white; min-width:10em}\n");
                   res.write("td {background-color:lightgrey}\n");
                   res.write("caption {font-weight:bold}</style>");
                   res.write("<table border='1'><caption>Form Data</caption>");
                   res.write("<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th>");
                   var dBody = querystring.parse(fullBody);
                   for (var prop in dBody) {
                       res.write("<tr><td>" + prop + "</td><td>"
                           + dBody[prop] + "</td></tr>");
                   }
                   res.write("</table></body></html>");
                   res.end();


       }

   }).listen(port);
   console.log("Ready on port " + port);
   ```
5. Type localhost:8888 in your browsers adress field

Hope this gives you some idea what to do next.

Comment: You are right. I realised, I was trying to open the html like in htdocs on the above server, however, I just needed to open the html(not in localhost) and the page posted the response I was expecting. I intend to get into nodejs more as it seems interesting. thanks mainguy :) @mainguy